# Python Kivy: bind a command inside popup executes command

Tags: python, popup, kivy

I want to have a popup for confirming that the user really wants to quit the app. Now when I try to bind commands to the two buttons, I can *only* add the dismiss directly inside the function, not via a callback. That may be ok.
But I can *only* call my closing routine through a callback, not inside the function. When I bind *quit_app()* inside this function it gets directly executed when opening the popup. Why? It just should bind, not execute.

```
(Old script deleted.)
```

I have updated my script a bit and included a minimum kv file. It works basically (like previously) but looks a bit odd.

**UI-Test.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
# Kivy imports:
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix import popup
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel


VersionString = "DRAFT"
AppName = 'UI-Test'

def CloseProgram(Message, Level):
     print('Closing, level {} ({})'.format(Level, Message))
     sys.exit()

def OnClosing(self):
    print('Closing...')
    # ToDo: call popup


def init():
    print('Starting {} Version {}.'.format(AppName, VersionString))
    print('You are using Python version: {}'.format(sys.version))


class TestApp(App):
    title = AppName + ' ' + VersionString

    def on_pause(self):
        return True

    def quit_app(self,btn):
        CloseProgram('Normal Closing', 'Debug')


    class Pop(BoxLayout):

        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(Pop, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            self.up()

        def callback(instance):
            if instance.id == 'quit':
                TestApp.quit_app(TestApp, 1)

        def up(self):
            print('popup')
            qbutton = Button(text='Quit', id='quit')
            abutton = Button(text='Return to Program', id='return')
            blayout = BoxLayout()
            blayout.add_widget(qbutton)
            blayout.add_widget(abutton)
            self.popup = kivy.uix.popup.Popup(title='Quit Program?', content=blayout, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
            abutton.bind(on_release=self.popup.dismiss)
            qbutton.bind(on_release=TestApp.Pop.callback)
            self.popup.open()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()
    TestApp().run()
```

**Test.kv:**

```
#:kivy 1.9

<Button>:
    font_size: 15

# Main Layout:
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Button:
        text: "Quit"
        id: "quit_button"
        size_hint: (0.1, None)
        size: (150, 50)
        on_release: app.Pop.up(self)
```

Comment: you are calling it ... instead use a lambda `on_release= lambda evt:aempApp.quit_app(aempApp, 1)` ...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Kivy, but your `callback` method appears to be missing its `self` arg. BTW, class names in Python normally begin with an uppercase letter. You don't _have_ to do that, but not doing so makes it confusing for other readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Question

> How would you call this popup from a kv file? When in my version (see
>   updated script) Pop is not part of TestApp I can't access it from kv
>   file

## Solution - with kv file

### kv file

1. Add import statement, `#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory`
2. Define class rule, `<Pop>:` and add widgets.
3. Register, instantiate, and open `class Pop()` using `Factory.Pop().open()`

[Factory object](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.factory.html)

> The factory can be used to automatically register any class or module
>   and instantiate classes from it anywhere in your project.

### Python Code

1. Use `App.get_running_app()` to get an instance of the `class TestApp()`

## Example - with kv file

### main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

# Kivy imports:
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup


VersionString = "DRAFT"
AppName = 'UI-Test'


def CloseProgram(Message, Level):
     print('Closing, level {} ({})'.format(Level, Message))
     sys.exit()


def OnClosing(self):
    print('Closing...')
    # ToDo: call popup


def init():
    print('Starting {} Version {}.'.format(AppName, VersionString))
    print('You are using Python version: {}'.format(sys.version))


class Pop(Popup):

    def callback(self, instance):
        App.get_running_app().quit_app(instance)


class TestApp(App):
    title = AppName + ' ' + VersionString

    def on_pause(self):
        return True

    def quit_app(self, btn):
        CloseProgram('Normal Closing', 'Debug')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    init()
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<Pop>:
    title: 'Quit Program?'
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 400

    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Quit'
            on_release:
                root.dismiss()
                root.callback(self)
        Button:
            text: 'Return to Program'
            on_release: root.dismiss()


<Button>:
    font_size: 15

# Main Layout:
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Button:
        text: "Quit"
        id: "quit_button"
        size_hint: (0.1, None)
        size: (150, 50)
        on_release: Factory.Pop().open()
```

## Output - with kv file

[image: Img01 - with kv file - Popup.QuitButton]
[image: Img02 - with kv file - Popup.QuitButton]

## Solution - without kv file

1. Bind all the buttons before calling `Popup.open()`
2. Use App.get_running_app() to get an instance of the class aempAPP

## Snippet

```
    def callback(self, instance):
        print("\ncallback:")
        self.popup.dismiss()
        App.get_running_app().quit_app(1)

    def up(self):
        ...
        self.popup = Popup(title='Quit Program?', content=blayout, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
        abutton.bind(on_release=self.popup.dismiss)
        qbutton.bind(on_release=self.callback)
        self.popup.open()

...
class aempApp(App):
    ...
    def quit_app(self, value):
        print(value)
```

## Example - without kv file

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class Pop(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Pop, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.up()

    def callback(self, instance):
        print("\ncallback:")
        self.popup.dismiss()
        App.get_running_app().quit_app(1)

    def up(self):
        print('popup')
        qbutton = Button(text='Quit', id='quit')
        abutton = Button(text='Return to Program', id='return')
        blayout = BoxLayout()
        blayout.add_widget(qbutton)
        blayout.add_widget(abutton)
        self.popup = Popup(title='Quit Program?', content=blayout, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
        abutton.bind(on_release=self.popup.dismiss)
        qbutton.bind(on_release=self.callback)
        self.popup.open()


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Pop()

    def quit_app(self, value):
        print("value=", value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

## Output - without kv file

[image: Img01 - without kv file]
[image: Img02 - without kv file - Clicked Quit button]

Comment: How would you call this popup from a kv file? When in my version (see updated script) Pop is not part of TestApp I can't access it from kv file.

Comment: In kv file, register, instantiate and open ` class Pop()` using `Factory.Pop().open()`. Please refer to my updated post.

Comment: Thank you! Works great. I use the kv version. Now the code looks much better. And I understand a bit more.